Can't create an Apple account to redeem a free trial for Apple TV service
I'm not an Apple person and don't own any Apple devices, but there's a few shows on Apple TV+ that look like they could be interesting. I got a promotion for a three month trial. When I click the link it takes me to the Apple site and has me create a new account, however no mater what I try I can't get past Add Payment Method. No matter what card I enter I get the error "Your PayPal account cannot be verified. Please correct your payment information." None of the payments have anything to do with PayPal. I tried two different MC and an AmEx, all of which received the same error. I've double and triple checked the card numbers, expiration dates, and CVV. Looking at the API calls it appears createAccountSvc is returning validationRuleName creditCardtype3. I've tried on both Chrome and Edge with no success. It doesn't say much for their service if you can't even create an account. Does anyone have any idea what this error means or how to get past it?

Based on a guess you are using Windows as you mention Edge, are you following the requirements as outlined here? https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/tvplus/apd581030aae/1.0/web/1.0

disable the popup blocker

Have you tried to create an account/login from https://account.apple.com/, enter your payment method there and then redeem the trial?

@Lulucmy Thank you. It's a very bad experience for non-Apple people. Going to account.apple.com I was partially able to log in to my account. I passed 2FA with email, then text, but then got stuck on the Continue button. It kept giving me a 500 error. But from there I was able to go to tv.apple.com and successfully start my trial.
